# Vue method return undefined when used in other method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to fetch replies of a comment in an object.
From the backend,i.e,LARAVEL I receive 1 object. But, in Vue it becomes undefined

**Method**

```
fetchReplies(commentid) {
  axios
    .get("/reply/" + commentid)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data != null) {
        console.log(res.data);
        return res.data;
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

**OutPut**

> (2) [{…}, {…}]            // for commentid 42

But When used this method in some other method

```
fetchComments() {
  var boardid = this.boardid;
  axios
    .get("/comment/" + boardid)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data != null) {
        this.comments = res.data;
           console.log(this.fetchReplies(42));
        }

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

**OutPut**

> Undefined

Before a while, when i fetch in Vue, I receive 1 object containing data and one with no data. But, suddenly that object with no data disappears.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with dummy data representing your issue?

Comment: How are you calling these methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What about returning something - in your .then / in the nested example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log(this.fetchReplies(42));` is calling a function which is still running as axios in asynchronous

If you make your `fetchComments` an `async function`, you can wait until your `fetchReplies` is finished before logging something.

Added a code snippet, make sure axios is returning something as well.

```
let results = await this.fetchReplies(42)
console.log(results)
```

```js
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            comments : '',
            replies : ''
        },
        methods: {
            fetchReplies(id) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    axios
                        .get(URL)
                        .then(res => {
                            if (res.data != null) {
                                resolve(res.data)
                            } else {
                                reject('RejectReason')
                            }

                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            reject(err)
                        });
                })
            },
            async fetchComments() {
                axios
                    .get(URL)
                    .then(async res => {
                        if (res.data != null) {
                            //Result from comments is in
                            this.comments = res.data;
                            let replies = await this.fetchReplies(1);
                            this.replies = replies;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="fetchComments()">
        Some text
    </button>
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    {{comments}}
    <h2>Replies</h2>
    {{replies}}
</div>
```

**Update:** Change snippet to change data visibly in template

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: i am still getting undefined

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot, thankyou so much.. That worked amazingly... I had made some mistake earlier but the snippet solved the problem.. thanks buddy

Comment: But this is not working in template.  I'm getting whole data in vue, but unable to access in template

Comment: @Qwerty Could you elaborate? you want to want to use the Axios results in your template I guess? To do that you first need to set a data attribute, which you can update in your methods.

Comment: Exactly, By this I did got data in my Vue, but when i try to use it in template, it says it's undefined

Comment: @Qwerty I changed the snippet. Basically, you define your template variables first and the page is just an empty string. If you click the button both functions run and update your template vars. If you want functions to run on page load, please look at The Vue Instance Lifecycle https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 0):

Axios is an asynchronous call, so it seems console.log is called before the fetch call has returned. The most convenient way to use axios call it with es2017 async/await.